# Loop through an array and concatenate the HTML for the image elements with its src's

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, loops

I am trying to output pictures of words based on the users input , i was wondering if there was a way to do it through Loop through an array and concatenate the HTML for the image elements with src's set to the corresponding image?

```
    //myArray
    var Signs = new Array("signa.jpg", "signb.jpg", "signc.jpg", "signd.jpg", "signe.jpg", "signf.jpg", "signg.jpg", "signh.jpg", "signi.jpg", "signj.jpg", "signk.jpg", "signl.jpg", "signm.jpg", "signn.jpg", "signo.jpg", "signp.jpg", "signq.jpg", "signr.jpg", "signs.jpg", "signt.jpg", "signu.jpg", "signv.jpg", "signw.jpg", "signx.jpg", "signy.jpg", "signz.jpg");


    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnGet").click(function () {

            var pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/);
            var UserInput;

            UserInput = $('#txt_name').val();
            //splits input
            UserInput = UserInput.split("");
            //gets data from input
            var userFirstName = trim($("#txt_name").val());
            text = text.toLowerCase();           //put all text into lower case 


        });//end of txt_name 

    });//end of btnGet

    //Trim function from http://www.somacon.com/p355.php
    function trim(stringToTrim) {
        return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What input do you have, what is the desired output, and what have you tried so far ? You can post your attempts even if it's not working yet

Comment: Sorry if im not clear; basically what the page is supposed to do is to output images of signs based on the user's input. Like lets say i input "David", there should come up the image for each letter, D,a,v,i, and d showing my name in images of sign language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code such as the following - this generates the html img tag for each letter and then injects these into a DOM element (assuming, for example, you have a div with id of "output":

```
var imageTags = $('#txt_name').val().split('').map (function(c) {return '<img src="img' + c + '.png" />';}, '');
$("#output").html(imageTags.join(''));
```

Here is a sample jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zdmmx49k/4/